# Remote database access architecture

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, architecture

Good day. I'm developing a website with the database which is going to be hosted in the cloud using Spring/Hibernate bundle. I also need to develop a desktop application that would be able to manage the remote database. I'm stuck choosing the appropriate method of implementing remote access. JAX-WS, RMI, Spring HttpInvoker or any other method? Which should I choose and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd choose JAX-WS/SOAP for this particular task.

Unlike binary protocols such as RMI, it goes easily over corporate proxies and firewalls. It  has security mechanisms (WS-Security), transaction and session support which I believe is important for database remote management.

It also has better tooling/IDE support than any other remote access method/API/framework.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service layer above dao layer and make it WS. Call WS from your web application and desktop application for using your db actions.

Answer (score 1):

Despite valuable answers of my predecessors, I would like you to analyze how complex system you are bulding and how many environmentally different clients such system would have. I mean, if there would be other applications, written in different technologies than Java involved in it. If it is so, the best solution is JAX-WS. Web services are standarized and can be used among various evironments, not only Java EE. But if you are going to build some very specific system used only by your applications, RMI should be enough.